# Propositional Resolution - How to prove?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was given the following argument which is valid. I must prove it using propositional resolution.

((A $\rightarrow$ B) $\rightarrow$ C)

(C $\rightarrow$ (D · E))

$∴ $ (B $\rightarrow$ D).

So then I found the following premises by converting the above argument to clausal form:

1. $\{A, -B\}$ - Premise
2. $\{C\}$ - Premise
3. $\{-C, D\}$ - Premise
4. $\{-C, E\}$ - Premise
5. $\{B, -D\}$ - Negated Conclusion

How would I apply Propositional resolution in this situation?

Comment: A premise is a logical statement, not a set of logical statements. Is each premise the combination of the statements in the set in some way?

Comment: That is not a standard logical relation. Does ">" there mean "implies"?

Comment: Use "\rightarrow" for $\rightarrow$

Comment: Please edit the question to present all of the information, including the information you've added in the comments. Making questions self contained greatly improves readability

Comment: This user seems to be editing his post every 60 seconds or so to keep it at the top.

Comment: Made a series of edits.

Comment: Are you sure about the first one ? $((A → B) → C)$ is $\lnot (\lnot A \lor B) \lor C$ i.e. $(A \land \lnot B) \lor C$.

Comment: In order to apply [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) you have to add to the premises the *negation* of the conclusion.

Comment: So if I fix the first premise and I remove the last premise, and replace it with the clausal form of the negation of the conclusion, am I on the right track? I'll make some edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first convert everything into clausal form.
$$((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C)$$
$$(-(-A \lor B) \lor C))$$
$$((A \land -B) \lor C)$$
$$(A \lor C) \land (-B \lor C)$$
This becomes two clauses
{A, -C} and {-B, C}
With $(C \rightarrow (D \land E))$, we get, {-C, D} and {-C, E}

In order to show that an argument is valid, we must show that 
$$Premise1 \land Premise2 \land ... \land -Conclusion$$
is a contradiction. You can right this out as a truth table, and check to see that all values in its column is zero (meaning a contradiction). However, you can slo try to resolve the above. If you resolve it and get an empty set, this implies a contradiction meaning that the argument is valid. That is what we are trying to do here.
The negation of teh conclusion is
$$(B \land -D)$$
This gives teh two clauses
{B} and {-D}
So now we have the following clauses to resolve. I'm going to number them to help keep track.

{A, C}1, {B, C}2, {-C, D}3, {-C, E}4, {B}5, {-D}6

Resolve 1 with 3

{A, D}1, {B, C}2, {-C, E}3, {B}4, {-D}5

Resolve 2 with 3

{A, D}1, {B, E}2, {B}3, {-D}4

Resolve 1 with 4

{A}1, {B, E}2, {B}3

And...I'm stuck. Would anyone like to point out my mistake? I can't see it.

Comment: You dropped a negation In the first line, which should be `{A, C}1, {-B, C}2, {-C, D}3, {-C, E}4, {B}5, {-D}6` ... Then resolve 2+3 :{-B, D} +5 : {D} +6 : contradiction.